# globally accessing const variables from a Vuex store

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I have a very simple VueJS example I'm having some trouble with.

I have a js file called enums.js with the following line in it

```
export const modeEnumeration = { PLAYBACK: 'playback', RECORDING: 'recording', NONE: 'none' };
```

I'd like to set the initial value of a property in Vuex state to one of these modeEnumeration values. So this is my Vuex store.

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Vuex from 'vuex';
import modeEnumeration from '../constants/enums';

Vue.use(Vuex);

export default new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    mode: modeEnumeration.NONE,
  },
  mutations: {
  },
  actions: {
  },
  modules: {
  },
  getters: {
  },
});
```

However, I keep getting the following error in my Vuex store...

**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'NONE' of undefined**

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You export a named object, so you need to import it with curly braces:

```
import { modeEnumeration } from '../constants/enums';
```

The other solution would be to export a default:

```
export default { PLAYBACK: 'playback', RECORDING: 'recording', NONE: 'none' };
```

Comment: Gosh, so simple. Thank you!